# Why does only one row display correctly when dumping MYSQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to dump my MYSQL table via PHP onto my HTML page and I'm having some issues that I've hit a bump on.

Currently I have (Using Bootstrap 4):

```
require('db.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`;";
$table = "";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

$table = "<table class='table table-hover table-dark'>";
$table .= "<thread>";
$table .= "<tr>";
$fieldsInfo = $result->fetch_fields();

foreach($fieldsInfo as $fieldinfo)
    $table .= "<th scope='col'>{$fieldinfo->name}</th>";
$table .= "</tr>";
$table .= "</thead>";
$table .= "<tbody>";


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $table .= "<tr>";

    foreach ($row as $columnValue) {
        $table .= "<td>$columnValue</td>";

    }
    $table .= "</tr>";
    $table .= "</tbody>";
    $table .= "</table>";
}
echo $table;
?>
```

And my result looks like so:
[Table Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaYs4.png)

I believe it's where I'm placing the `<tr>` and `</tr>` values in my code, but I've tried placing them both inside and out side of my loops. When placed inside of my loop my table returns all my column values into the first table heading. I further inspected my code via Firefox 'inspect element' and I saw that the second row from the table is actually outside the scope of `<table>` which makes no sense to me because my loop is obviously before I use `</table>`.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me, I'm just starting to use PHP so I'm not great with it; but I want to learn.

Comment: You've closed the tbody and table tags inside your while loop. Move those closing tags outside the loop and it should fix it.

Comment: Fixed it. I feel such an idiot I didn't catch that. Can you please answer the question so I can mark it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, no problem. No need to feel like an idiot; it happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags look fine where they are. The problem is that the closing `</tbody>` and `</table>` tags are inside the while loop. Move them down and it should come out right.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $table .= "<tr>";

    foreach ($row as $columnValue) {
        $table .= "<td>$columnValue</td>";

    }
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</tbody>";
$table .= "</table>";
echo $table;
```

Comment: Table is displaying how it should now. Can't believe I was trying to move the `td` and I didn't even catch the `table` and `tbody` inside the loop!

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make. One thing I've used to quickly spot markup errors like that is "view page source" in Firefox. It highlights invalid tags in red. I wish chrome would do the same, since I use it for most other stuff.

Comment: I didn't even realize that. Reverted my code to when it had errors and used "View Page Source", amazing. I would have caught it so easy if I would have known. Thanks for the extra advice, that's going to help me quite a bit while I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $table .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $columnValue) {
        $table .= "<td>$columnValue</td>";
    }
    $table .= "</tr>";

}
$table .= "</tbody>";
$table .= "</table>";
```

Comment: `</tbody>` should not be inside the while loop either.